# how can i monitor iccube server and data via an external tool

Tags: iccube

I'd like to put iccube under solid monitoring so that we know when a) cube load failure or b) cube last update time exceeded the expected.

is there an api i can use to integrate with standard monitoring tools?rest, command-line etc ...

thanks in advance, assaf

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the schema load failure you can check the notification service ([www](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/configuring_iccube/iccube_notification_xml.php)); you can for example receive an eMail on failure. Note that you can implement (JAVA) your own transport service to receive notifications. There is no "notification" for last update time exceeded but if you could use an external LOAD command ([www](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/using/cube_management.php)) for loading your schema; in that case you will know the last update time and perform whatever logic required.

Edit: XMLA commands can be sent via any tools (e.g., [Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165435/xmla-soap-command-from-a-bash-shell)).

Hope that helps.

Comment: i can get the last update via mdx. is there a way to authenticate and execute mdx via some sort of api? cmi?

Comment: Edited my response