# How to execute xmla command on iccube?

Tags: iccube, xmla

Seing [cube_management](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/using/cube_management.php) page, I see we can execute xmla commands like LIST_SCHEMA_BACKUP

Seing [xmla](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/running_iccube/xmla.php) page, I see we can connect to xmla using `http://localhost:8282/icCube/xmla` in a navigator

Is there a way to execute directly commands from a navigator with something like `http://localhost:8282/icCube/xmla?command="LIST_SCHEMA_BACKUP"`

Or, what is the simplest way to execute a xmla command against iccube ?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165435/xmla-soap-command-from-a-bash-shell?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to execute such a command using a REST like syntax. The best way is to use a script to wrap the actual SOAP call. You can look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165435/xmla-soap-command-from-a-bash-shell?rq=1) for more details.

Hope that helps.